# Which confidence intervals should be used?

Tags: r, confidence-interval, methodology

I would like to plot 95% confidence intervals for my data. It seems there are multiple options for calculating them, e.g.: (examples shown using R code)

```
library(psych)

# Make some data
set.seed(1)
N <- 10
data <- data.frame(A.1=rnorm(N, 1, 1), A.2=rnorm(N,2,1), B.1=rnorm(N,2,1),
B.2=rnorm(N, 1, 1))
data

desc <- describe(data)
alpha <- 0.05


# Either:
# (1) using 1.96 (the quantile from the normal distribution)
ci <- desc$se * 1.96
    # or ci <- desc$se * qnorm(1-alpha/2)

# (2) using the quantile from the t distribution
ci <- desc$se * qt(1-alpha/2, desc$n - 1)

# Note that 1 and 2 would be used like this:
# upper <- desc$mean + ci
    # lower <- desc$mean - ci

# (3) using R's confint function:
ci <- confint(lm(values ~ 0 + ind, stack(data)))

# (4) using the trimmed mean:
library(WRS)
ci <- apply(data, 2, trimci)

# (5) various bootstrap methods, e.g.:
ci <- apply(data, 2, trimcibt)
```

I am a bit lost as to which method I should be using. I understand bootstrap methods should be more accurate because they do not assume the distribution is normal, but I rarely see them applied in practice.

Does anyone have any guidelines or advice?

Comment: For a `lm` `confint` uses *t*-based intervals, and for `glm` it uses the profile method. Calling `confint.default` directly uses the asymptotic normality assumption. Bootstrap methods are more computationally intensive, but do not rely on underlying assumptions about the error distribution. If the results from the different methods differ significantly, there is likely a violation of the assumptions.

Comment: Bootstrapped methods are rarely employed because 1) Some people don't know about them 2) Some of the people who know they exist don't know how to use them 3) It's easier to assume and go from there.